# An error was thrown in afterAll; Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

After upgrading from Angular 15 to 15.1 I'm encountering an error when executing tests in my angular project.
I could reproduce this by simply setting up a new Angular 15.1 project via the CLI and generating a service using the same semantic as the (probably problematic) service in my project.

## Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StorageServiceService {
  public static readonly A = 'a';
  public static readonly B = StorageServiceService.A + 'b';
  public static readonly C = StorageServiceService.A + 'c';

  constructor() { }
}
```

## Test

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { StorageServiceService } from './storage-service.service';

describe('StorageServiceService', () => {
  let service: StorageServiceService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(StorageServiceService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('test', () => {
    expect(StorageServiceService.A).toEqual('a')
    expect(StorageServiceService.B).toEqual('ab')
    expect(StorageServiceService.C).toEqual('ac')
  })
});
```

When executing the tests I'm retrieving the following error:

```
Chrome 109.0.0.0 (Mac OS 10.15.7) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'A')
  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'A')
      at Object.2494 (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/storage-service.service.ts:8:52)
      at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
      at Object.283 (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/main.js:86:82)
      at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
      at __webpack_exec__ (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/main.js:186:48)
      at http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/main.js:187:126
      at Function.__webpack_require__.O (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/runtime/chunk loaded:23:1)
      at http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/main.js:188:56
      at webpackJsonpCallback (http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/runtime/jsonp chunk loading:34:1)
```

I'm using Node 18.12.1 with npm 9.2.0.

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
}
```

After downgrading to Angular 15 this seems to work fine. I did the angular upgrade via the angular CLI and not manually.

Comment: Did you get this working? I have the same issue as this with a service which has a method which sets the service configuration. I'm on ng 14.2 however

Comment: My workaround is to avoid static members unfortunately. This issue seems to be related to [This GitHub Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52004) in TypeScript.

Comment: Interestingly the method I have the issue with is not static, my issue is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76034835/410622

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't be your test code like this?

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { StorageServiceService } from './storage-service.service';

describe('StorageServiceService', () => {
    let service: StorageServiceService;
    
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
        service = TestBed.inject(StorageServiceService);
    });
    
    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });
    
    it('test', () => {
        expect(service.A).toEqual('a')
        expect(service.B).toEqual('ab')
        expect(service.C).toEqual('ac')
    })
});
```

Comment: No, as A, B and C are static members of StorageServiceService. This won't compile.

Comment: can;t import outsid a module.