# Error thrown in afterAll, cannot set properties of `undefined` in Angular unit test (jasmine)

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I am getting the following error when running unit tests for an angular service:

> An error was thrown in afterAll   TypeError: Cannot set properties of
> undefined (reading 'setConfiguration')

The service implements this interface:

```
export interface ILookupDataService<T> {
    search(searchTerm: string): Observable<T[]>;
    setConfiguration(config: LookupServiceConfiguration): void;
}
```

... this is the implementation:

```
export class LookupDataService<T> implements ILookupDataService<T> {

  private configuration: LookupServiceConfiguration;
  constructor(private readonly httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  private get absolutePath(): string {
    return `${this.formatUrlFragment(this.configuration.baseUrl)}${this.formatUrlFragment(this.configuration.apiPrefix)}${this.configuration.endpoint}`;
  }

  setConfiguration(config: LookupServiceConfiguration) {
    this.configuration = config;
  }

  search(searchTerm: string): Observable<T[]> {
    const url = `${this.absolutePath}?${this.configuration.searchTermParamName}=${searchTerm}`;
    return this.httpClient.get<T[]>(url)
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => { throw err; })
      );
  }

  private formatUrlFragment(fragment: string): string {
    if (fragment.startsWith('/')) {
      fragment = fragment.substring(1);
    }
    return fragment.endsWith('/') ? fragment : `${fragment}/`;   
  }
}
```

So any component using this service must inject the configuration manually using the `setConfiguration` method.

However when I run tests I get the previously specified error, my spec file is below. Do I need to do something in the setup to define `setConfiguration`?

```
describe('LookupDataService', () => {
  let service: LookupDataService<SomeEntity>;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(LookupDataService);
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('Search', () => {
    // arrange
    service.setConfiguration(config);
    const searchTerm = 'someSearchTerm';
    const expectedUrl = `${config.baseUrl}/${config.apiPrefix}${config.endpoint}?${config.searchTermParamName}=${searchTerm}`;

    it('should call the correct URL with expected method and return the expected entities', () => {
      // arrange
      const expectedEntites = [
        new SomeEntity(1, 'someCode'),
        new SomeEntity(2, 'anotherCode')
      ];

      // act
      service.search(searchTerm).subscribe(actual => {
        expect(actual).toEqual(expectedEntites);
      });

      // assert
      const req = httpMock.expectOne(expectedUrl);
      expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
      req.flush(expectedEntites);
    });
  });
});
```

Running:

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.10
Node: 16.19.0
npm 8.19.3
typescript: 4.6.4
```